# Limit download usage for clients

Tags: linux, windows, rhel5, quota

i am maintaining few windows xp machines under rhel 5 . i want to set quota for download file size. How to do it ?

I mean, in lan usar A's maximum donload file size is 300 MB , and user B's maximum download file size in 200 MB. I want to block downloading when user try to download more than 300 MB file.User should not allow to download 300MB file at a time.

Or how to set quota for maximum download per day, is there possible to do it ?

- How can i do this ?

Comment: Are you running any kind of proxy currently? Does it need to run on the RHEL server? Windows Domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for Linux NAT only solution (i.e. no proxy), you could use connbytes iptables rule to track maximum number of bytes transferred through one TCP connection; for daily quota you could setup some set of rules (one per ip-address) using the 'quota' rule. However, since the HTTP connection can pack many downloads into one connections, it may not be reliable. To get something better, you would have to use HTTP proxy - e.g. squid can limit the maximum size of the resulting file.

Comment: Can you please tell how can i do it by squid ? any links ?

Comment: Google for "squid delay pools".